# Calculating Coordinate transformations

Tags: coordinate-system

Given 3 or 4 known points can I generate transformation equations to wgs-84. How would I do this.  I wont know what coordinate system the original 3-4 points are in.

Comment: I think you need to know a little more: is your original coordinate system distance preserving? angle preserving? Is it just a rotation of WGS-84? There are literally hundreds (or infinite, allowing for parameters) map projections (proj4 lists many), so 3-4 points may not be enough.

Comment: Assume distance preserving.  Basically I want to build a tool where the user uploads a map (it could be a pdf) clicks on so many points and assigns them GPS coordinates and then generate a new svg file that can be loaded into leaflet

Comment: This looks like georeferencing against WGS84. GDAL has the necessary commandline tools for that.